# Как импортировать базу mysql (5.5.28) на сервер mysql (5.1.49)?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте!

На сервере mysql версия 5.5.28, эскпортирую базу через phpmyadmin, и потом импортирую на сервер с mysql 5.1.49, выдает ошибку.

Ошибка

SQL-запрос:

```
 -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net -- -- Хост: u314082.mysql.masterhost.ru -- Время создания: Фев 22 2013 г., 12:20 -- Версия сервера: 5.5.28 -- Версия PHP: 5.3.3 SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */; /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */; /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */; -- -- База данных: `u314082_4` -- -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Структура таблицы `jos_banner` -- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_banner` ( `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'banner', `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `imptotal` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `impmade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `clicks` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `imageurl` varcha[...] `
```

Ответ MySQL:

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARA' at line 13`

Я удалил строку 13 и еще там несколько и все равно ошибка, помогите, кто может, спасибо.

Comment: какая ошибка? и что говорит гугл?

Comment: @qwerty17, в качестве наглой и неприкрытой рекламы :) Если к обеим базам есть прямой доступ, рекомендую программку HeidiSQL (для Windows, но HTTP-туннелей там пока нет, только SSH). Она самостоятельно умеет импортировать и экспортировать базы напрямую, без промежуточных дампов, но с контролем разных версий MySQL.

Comment: +сану, программа огонь!

Comment: для новичка в этом она не сложная? мануал на русском есть?

Comment: Русского там нет, да и не надо, всё элементарно и предельно просто. phpMyAdmin на порядок сложней в освоении, даже на русском :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! заинтриговал! попробую сейчас)))

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу, вы пользовались `phpmyadmin` для экспорта, потому рекомендую в настройках экспорта выставить **`Export Method: Custom - display all possible options`**  потом в **`Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with`**: выберите **`MYSQL40`**

Comment: спасибо! но где это найти? у меня интерфейс phpmyadmin на русском)я выбрал нужную базу.. выделил все таблицы... выделил экспорт в sql формат... вот этих слов Export Method: Custom - display all possible options потом в Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:  я не вижу..

Comment: Экспорт таблиц из базы данных выбираете: Обычный - отображать все возможные настройки

появится много опций там в разделе Параметры формата: выберите Максимальная совместимость с системой базы данных, или устаревшей версией MySQL: MYSQL40

Comment: и как они пишут программы и скрипты.....

Comment: Как пишут - так потом всё и работает :)

Comment: binliz там даже таких опций нет...Обычный - отображать все возможные настройки...таких слов в разделе Экспорт в phpmyadmin просто нет.. или я слепой))))

Comment: по моему это не по существу, у человека есть жумла он ее переносит ему паралельно как работает скрипт он просто хочет ее перенести, и просит чтобы ему подсказали как это сделать. К чему тут написание скриптов? Или вы уверены что в жумла пользуются всем новым из mysql5 хранимыми процедурами, связями между таблицами?

Comment: скачайте нормальную версию phpmyadmin... какая у вас версия? все там есть! на самом верху

задампите в конце концов mysqldump --compatible=mysql4

Comment: извините, просто я новичек в этом) у меня базы на мастерхосте.. и как менять там версию phpmyadmin я к сожалению не знаю( но все равно спасибо... вроде что-то нашел... режим совместимости при экспорте надо ставить  mysql40... и при импорте тоже надо ставить этот режим совместимости?

Comment: ну мы тож не телепаты где у вас что стоит))) можно.

Comment: ))))))) это точно))))